# Duplicate shared object on fms

Tags: flash, flash-media-server, shared-objects

I wanted to create a copy of a temporary shared object on server to another permanent shared object. What would be the efficient way of doing that?

Thank you,
Naresh

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it is the more efficient way to do it at all, but one good old solution is to use a `for` loop :

```
var names = source.getPropertyNames();
for (var prop:String in names)
{
    var value:Object = source.getProperty(names[prop]);
    destination.setProperty(names[prop], value);
}
```